# How can I use AWK to remove "name" columns and only print the kvm* fields?

Tags: awk, grep

I need a bit of help parsing a list. I've got it till the "name" column but need to take it a bit further and drop off the "Name" tag and keep only the list (i.e. kvm670...kvm673). For example:

```
[root@la04 net]#  virsh list | awk '{print $2}''
Name

kvm670
kvm671
kvm672
kvm673
```

How can I print only the kvm* fields?

Comment: Show the raw `virsh` ouput. Dropping those lines from that output is simple but it might be simpler to only print the output you want in the first place.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, will keep in mind when I post my next question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pattern to only print lines of interest. For example:

```
virsh list | awk '/kvm[[:digit:]]+/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know awk could handle the whole thing, will readup on awk :)